# laravel multiple where clauses within a loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Pretty much I want the query to select all records of users that are 25 years old AND are either between 150-170cm OR 190-200cm.

I have this query written down below.  However the problem is it keeps getting 25 year olds OR people who are 190-200cm instead of 25 year olds that are 150-170 OR 25 year olds that 190-200cm tall. How can I fix this?   thanks

```
 $heightarray=array(array(150,170),array(190,200));
 $user->where('age',25);

   for($i=0;$i<count($heightarray);i++){
 if($i==0){
   $user->whereBetween('height',$heightarray[$i])
}else{
   $user->orWhereBetween('height',$heightarray[$i])
 }
 }
      $user->get();
```

Edit: I tried advanced wheres (http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres) and it doesn't work for me as I cannot pass the $heightarray parameter into the closure.

from laravel documentation

```
 DB::table('users')
        ->where('name', '=', 'John')
        ->orWhere(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                  ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: You need to make use of [advance wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres).

Comment: I tried that but I can't pass variables into the closures

Comment: Can you post the advanced where statement that you tried?

Comment: I did something simliar Jeemusu in the bottom

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like [Jeemusu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19485994/93216) and the OP stated, you need to use [advance wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres).
But if you want to pass a variable to the closure function you need to make use of the "**use**" approach:

```
$heightarray = array(array(150,170),array(190,200));

DB::table('users')
  ->where('name', '=', 'John')
  ->orWhere(function($query) use ($heightarray){
    //...
  })
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is completely untested, but looking at the documentation for [advance wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres), it would seem you want to try something like this:

```
DB::table('users')
->where('age',25)
->Where(function($query)
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($heightarray);i++){
       if($i==0){
          $query->whereBetween('height', $heightarray[$i]);
       }else{
          $query->orWhereBetween('height', $heightarray[$i]);
       }
    }
})->get();
```

Comment: I tried that but you need to pass heightarray into the closure otherwise it doesn't know what you are talking about

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.  I need to include "use" in the closure to pass my $heightarray variable in.  Once $heightarray  is in then laravel's advance wheres work.

```
$heightarray=array(array(150,170),array(190,200));
  $user->where('age',25);

 $userprofile->Where(function($query) use ($heightarray) {

 for($i=0;$i<count($heightarray);i++){
 if($i==0){
 $user->whereBetween('height',$heightarray[$i])
 }else{
 $user->orWhereBetween('height',$heightarray[$i])
  }
}

 });

  $user->get();
```